# parsing XML web service

Tags: php

i have this code controler CI:

```
function cek_xml() {
        $response = $_SESSION ['nim'];

        // fetch data
       $respons = $this->curl->simple_get($url = "http://localhost/restful/index.php/restful/buku/nim/$response/format/xml");

        if (empty($response)) {
            show_error('can`t access :' . $response);
        }


        $data['cuaca'] = $this->format->factory($respons, 'xml')->to_array();

       $this->load->view('data_buku_XML', $data);
    }
```

in view :

```
   <?php $no=1;?>
        <?php //$this->benchmark->mark('rest_start'); ?>

        <?php foreach ($cuaca as $row) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($row as $row) { ?>

        <tr class="<?php echo ($no % 2 == 0) ?>">

                        <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['loan_date'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['due_date'] ?></td>
        <?php $no=$no+1;?>
        </tr>

        <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
```

The problem is when i get the title, loan date, due date more than one variable it's okay.

But if get 1 title it's will show:

> Message: Illegal string offset 'title'

But if i put `//` like in one `foreach`:

```
// foreach ($row as $row) {
```

It will show 1 variable title but error in more one variable ...

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing same name for variables
Change the variable name

```
<?php foreach ($row as $r)
```

and use as

```
<td><?php echo $r['title']; ?></td>
```

Comment: if i use two foreach like this : 
"<?php foreach ($cuaca as $row) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($row as $rowsub) { ?>"

i get the result like this :
No. title               loan__date due_date
1 PHP 5 for dummies 2013-12-17 2013-12-31
2 PostgreSQL          2013-12-17 2013-12-31

this is two title, if i want to get one title i have to put // in one foreach...
like this  <?php //foreach ($row as $r) { ?>

thanks....